# How do I edit a form in ServiceNow

Tags: servicenow

I've been given an exercise. Add a field to the Tasks table and make sure it is visible on the incident form as a drop down list. So I've added a column to the table. But how do I then get that drop down list on to the incidents form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load up an incident record and then right click on the header of the form. Then go to configure and then click form layout. You can also use the form designer. In either situation, just drag the field from the left to the right. In the form designer it's a little bit easier to choose exactly where you want the field to show up.

Pro tip: you can easily get to the incident form by typing "incident.form" into the application navigator filler bar on the left and pressing enter.

If you want to learn more about ServiceNow, I humbly welcome you to check out my best-selling book: "Learning ServiceNow" at http://lsn.sngeek.com/

Comment: One last thing, do I need to create the update set before I make the changes?

Comment: if you intend to move the changes to another instance, lets say Prod for example, then yes you will have to create an update set. Prior to any changes you make in the form